# Change to 24h. mode of DateRangeFilter

Tags: google-apps-script, filter, google-api, google-visualization, date-range

I have a DateRangeFilter in Google Script Visualisation Dashboard, but when i set it shows as

> 17/12/23 02:31:43 PM

instead of

> 17/12/23 14:31:43

My curent code is:

```
    var timestamp = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'DateRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'timestamp_div',
    options: {
         filterColumnIndex: 0,
         ui:{ step: 'second'}
    }
});
```

How can change it to 24h. mode? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `ui.format` option...

which should be an object, with the following properties...

> `formatType` - A quick formatting option for the date. The following string values are supported, reformatting the date February 28, 2016 as shown:
>   `'short'` - Short format: e.g., "2/28/16"
>   `'medium'` - Medium format: e.g., "Feb 28, 2016"
>   `'long'` - Long format: e.g., "February 28, 2016"
>
> `pattern` - A custom format pattern to apply to the value, similar to the ICU date and time format. You cannot specify both formatType and pattern.
>
> `timeZone` - The time zone in which to display the date value. This is a numeric value, indicating GMT + this number of time zones (can be negative).

here the `pattern` property is used...

```
      ui: {
        format: {
          pattern: 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'
        },
        step: 'second'
      }
```

to get 24 hour formatting, use uppercase H's for the hour segment --> `HH`
(lowercase will give 12 hour formatting)

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2017, 11, 28, 14, 31, 43)],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 29, 15, 32, 44)],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 30, 16, 33, 45)],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 31, 17, 34, 46)],
    [new Date(2018, 0, 1, 18, 35, 47)],
    [new Date(2018, 0, 2, 19, 36, 48)]
  ]);

  var timestamp = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'DateRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'timestamp_div',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: 0,
      ui: {
        format: {
          pattern: 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'
        },
        step: 'second'
      }
    }
  });
  timestamp.draw();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timestamp_div"></div>
```